# How long before Order 66 does Dark Disciple take place?

Tags: star-wars, time

It is established that the book *Dark Disciple* takes place in 19 BBY, the same year as *Revenge of the Sith* and Order 66.  Is there any evidence as to just how much time there is between *Dark Disciple* and Order 66?

Comment: Probably a few rotations or something.

Comment: established where (outside of the wiki)?